# How to open a pdf file generated with itext 7 in new browser tab java

Tags: java, file, pdf, itext7

I make a pdf file in java using itext 7 and can save it on my local computer.

How can I open this file in new browser tab somehow without storing it on my computer?

Comment: Create a java servlet and set the pdf mimetype to your result in response.

Comment: You say " in new browser tab", so there seems to be an old tab from which you have triggered the PDF generation. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. Forgot to note that. I make a browser app based on vaadin and spring. And at one page i click button to generate this pdf file and need directly to open that file in new browser tab without storing it on server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem that.

Here I generate a pdf file and return his StreamResource:

```
public static StreamResource generateTestPdf(){
    ByteArrayOutputStream dest = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest);
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);
    Document document = new Document(pdfDoc);

    Paragraph title = new Paragraph("Hello World!");
    document.add(title);
    StreamResource streamResource = null;
    try {
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    document.close();

    ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(dest.toByteArray());
     streamResource = new StreamResource("file.pdf", new InputStreamFactory() {
        @Override
        public InputStream createInputStream() {
            return inputStream;
        }
    });

     return streamResource;
}
```

After that I add on my page a Button with listener, that opens generated file in browser new tab:

```
Button print = new Button("Print");  
print.addClickListener(e -> {
                    this.close();
            final StreamRegistration registration = VaadinSession.getCurrent().getResourceRegistry().registerResource(PdfGenerator.generateTestPdf());
            UI.getCurrent().getPage().setLocation(registration.getResourceUri());
                }
        );
```

I don’t know how correct this solution is, but it worked for me. Thanks to all!

P.S. I use Vaadin 14 and Itext 7.1.12